# High-pitched intermittent noise from base of Lenovo laptop (SSD)

Tags: hardware-failure, fan, noise

My new Lenovo T550 laptop, running Windows 7, seems to be always making a strange noise, coming from its bottom (base).

As this laptop is equipped with an SSD hard-drive, I would have expected it to be completely silent. The noise is high-pitched and intermittent/noisy. It is not loud, however in a quiet environment it is noticeable and irritating. The noise is always on, i.e. not just when the CPU is under high load, and does not seem to be correlated with anything that's going on in the software. Indeed this is not the CPU fan, as that comes on sometimes under heavy software load, and makes a different (more tolerable) noise.

[Here](http://www.2shared.com/audio/q5Aq21JC/lenovo_T550_noise.html) is a WAV file that I recorded with my phone, holding the microphone next to the base of the laptop. I would really appreciate some advice with regard to what this noise might be due to, and if there are any software settings that might get rid of it. I doubt it is "normal" and would think that indicates that the laptop (or parts of it) need to be replaced.

Comment: It is not possible for a SSD to make noise.  So you likely have a capacitor that needs to be replaced, if you have never done that before, if the machine functions you should just ignore it.  You can do more harm replacing the capacitor yourself if you don't have the soldering skills required to do so.

Comment: Does it emit the noise even when it is not connected to AC power?

Comment: @TomYan: yes, it is irrespective of whether the ac is connected or not

Comment: @Ramhound: I take it you have listened to the WAV and you are positive that this is what is generating the sound? The machine does function, however its user (me) is not happy with this sound

Comment: Sounds like something coming from the speakers (when they are "listening" to an empty line-in/mic jack). I bet you've tried muting them already though?

Comment: I have yes, definitely not from the speakers but from the small vents/holes located centrally on the base of the laptop,

Comment: There is actually some correlation with CPU load that I notice, though a negative one: when an intensive operation is being carried out, the noise disappears completely, and only comes back when the PC is back to being idle. Very strange..

Comment: @longtalker - No;  But I have been around electronics my entire life.  high-pitched sounds are often caused by capacitors.